# Haml.js: Is there any way to insert dynamic attribute value?

Tags: haml

There's what I want to do:

```
%input.current-page( type="text" value=currentPageNum )
```

where **currentPageNum** is dynamic.

That's how I invoke this template:

```
@$el.html( Haml.render( @template, { locals: { currentPageNum: @currentPageNum } } ) )
```

**This Question is about haml.js but I don't have enough reputation to create new tag here**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer:

`%input.current-page{ type: "text", value: "#{currentPageNum}" }`

Further reading:

https://github.com/creationix/haml-js/blob/master/test/embedded_code.haml

comparing with

https://github.com/creationix/haml-js/blob/master/test/embedded_code.html

Comment: you've probably realized this by now, but the interpolation is unnecessary: `%input.current-page{ type: "text", value: currentPageNum }`